# How to number subsection of a nonumber section?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

To number the subsection, I use

> \renewcommand*\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

It works well for the normal numbered sections. For example, if we use

```
\section{A}  
\subsection{try}
\subsection{try2}
```

it shows

```
1. A
1.1. try
1.2. try2
```

However, if one section is not numbered, the subsections within it looks weird. For example, if we write

```
\section*{A}
\subsection{try}
\subsection{try2}
```

we get

```
A
.1. try
.2. try
```

How can I write a macros to make an automatic judgement: if the section is numbered, this number is added to subsection numbering; if the section is not numbered, we directly number subsection by itself? As an example, I want to get

```
1. A
1.1. A1
1.2. A2

B
1. B1
2. B2
```

Comment: Don't do this! The readers will be lost with such navigation through your text.

Comment: I hope it is obvious why this would be a weird thing to do, but look at your redefinition of `\subsection`.  Then use: `\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}` at the point where you want the redefinition to take place. You will probably also have to reset the subsection counter: `\setcounter{subsection}{0}`. (But, really, don't do this.).

Comment: Thank you all. Yes it is a bad idea. Following jon's, maybe it is good to \renewcommand*\thesubsection{*.\arabic{subsection}} and \setcounter{subsection}{0} at the point of nonumber-sections to make it clear.

Comment: If you acknowledge this is a bad idea, why are you still trying to do it?

Comment: This is document class and/or package dependent behavior.  The default for book, report or article is to number subsections the way you do, but \section*{A} should not affect the section counter at all.  Subsections should act like they are still in the last section (or section 0).

Comment: The same headers with two different numeric counts is really a bad idea. If this is a must, at least use roman numbers, or letters and do not forget limit the scope of the changes . That is: `{\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\alph{subsection})} \section*{...} \subsection{...} ....  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may make sense within the document body, but the ToC formatting will require some consideration.

Below I've updated the way `\section` works. It conditions on `*` and reformats the `\thesubsection` counter accordingly - either removing the prepended `\thesection.` or inserting it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{#3}% \section*
     \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}}% Update subsection numbering
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}% \section
     {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
     {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
     \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}% Update subsection numbering
    }%
  \setcounter{subsection}{-1}\stepcounter{subsection}% Reset all sub-counters beyond \subsection
}

% Add period after sectional numbers in document body and ToC
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}

\section*{B}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\subsection{Fourth subsection}

\section*{C}
\subsection{Fifth subsection}
\subsection{Sixth subsection}

\section{D}
\subsection{Seventh subsection}
\subsection{Eighth subsection}

\end{document}
```